# Substring In For in Java Netbeans

Tags: java, for-loop

```
String x = grades.getText();
String [] grades = new String [100]; 
for (int i = 0; i < x.length() ;i++) {
    if (x.charAt(i) == ',') {
        grades[i] = x.substring(0, i);
        x = x.substring(i + 1, x.length());
        System.out.println(grades[i]);
    }
}
```

In this code I want the Array grades hava all the grades whice I entered to x String.

> The x string should look like this: `"3,5,6,7"`

And I want every string in the Array will get the number  without the "," .
So it should print this:

```
3 //saved in grades[0];
5 //saved in grades[1];
6 //saved in grades[2];
7 //saved in grades[3];
```

But it prints that:

```
"3 5"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you got two variables called `grades` in your code? That won’t work. We can help you the best with wrong output if you post compilable and runnable code so we may reproduce your problematic behaviour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How split string to array (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49712312/how-split-string-to-array-java) - ref. to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49712383/4892907

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, based on Ruslan's answer.

```
String x = grades.getText();
String[] gradesArray = x.split(","); 
for (int i=0; i < gradesArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(gradesArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: String x = classes1.getText();  It's shows me an error in this line he said "cannot find symble "

Comment: String x = classes1.getText(); It's shows me an error in this line he said "cannot find symble "

Comment: Where does the classes1 come from? Your original code used grades. If the original code compiled, then my answer should work correctly.

Comment: Now it's working but in the output it prints :  
3 (line down)
5,6                 ( with out the 7)

Comment: If grades.getText() puts "3,5,6,7" in the String x, then it will print out each number on a seperate line. Please check your code again, so it is exactly like the answer.

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: Hi, I have another question,   Do you have an idea why this code is not working?

Comment: String y = classes.getText();
        int z = 0;
        String[] classesArray = new String[z];
        classesArray[z] = y;
        z++;
        grades.setText(" ");
        classes.setText(" ");

Comment: You  initialize the String[] classesArray with z for length, which is 0. This results in an array with no place to put your text in. :-/ The array index is 0-based, but the array initialization needs to be at least 1 if you want to store something in it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do such complicated `for` loop. There is [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method:

```
String[] grades = x.split(",");
```

Comment: Can you write the code with the split because it's still not working to me

Comment: @LielKont This is all the code you need to get array with grades. Then you can print it in a for loop like `for(String g : grades) {System.out.println(g);}` Note: you can't have 2 variable with the same name. So rename the array or the variable you get `getText` from

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you wonder why your code is working wrong,

Each iteration after reducing `x`,you should look begin of the `x` which is `0` but your i will not come to `0` again,so you should force it,

```
String x = grades.getText();
    String [] grades = new String [100]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length() ;i++) {
        if (x.charAt(i) == ',') {
            grades[i] = x.substring(0, i);
            x = x.substring(i + 1, x.length());
            System.out.println(grades[i]);
            i = 0;
        }
    }
      System.out.println(x); //last x will your last element
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your code should look like, in order to print it as you request it.

```
String x = grades.getText();
String [] grades = x.split(",");
for(String grade : grades){
    System.out.println(grade);
}
```

Comment: it's working but in the output it prints : 3 (line down) 5,6            (without the 7)

Comment: @LielKont if you dont want a new line, you need to remove the "ln" part of println. So: System.out.print(grade);

Comment: @LielKont If the last grade in your text is not printing, then i would take a look at your: getText() function in grades. It might not return the correct string.